# What's beautiful in CS?

Tags: theory

I'm afraid this may be opinion-based and not apt here, but...

Mathematicians often talk about ["mathematical beauty"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty), i.e. Gauss' proof of the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), etc.

What's beautiful in Computer Science?
Things like the Church-Turing thesis or Curry-Howard correspondence are cool, but I'm not sure they are the same kind of "beauty" as mathematicians commonly prescribe.

Is it because CS is often an engineering field (despite its theories), and doesn't share the same notion of "beauty"?

Comment: I flagged the question as opinion-based.

Comment: Our educated sisters at cstheory.SE are keeping track of the most elegant/insightful algorithms in their list of [Algorithms from the Book](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/189/algorithms-from-the-book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is very opinion based. What's the difference between "cool" and "beautiful"? I find the Curry-Howard isomorphism beautiful, you don't. Neither of us is wrong.

Ultimately, Computer Science is a science of compromise. Mathematics is concerned with what "is": logical facts, pure truth and knowledge. Computer Science is concerned with what can be computed, and thanks to undecidability, that's really not that much.
There are uncountably many undecidable sets, but only countably many decidable ones.

So the mathematicians get to write beautiful pictures and draw beautiful diagrams about what is, in the abstract. And the computer scientists get to find the heuristics, the edge cases, the conservative approximations, and the impossibility results. In some sense, ours is a science of ugliness.

That said, everyone will find something beautiful in their field. In mine (Programming Languages), there's a whole category of paper called "Pearl" papers, where the design of something complex is made particularly simple or elegant by the programming language or technique used to create it. If you google "ICFP Functional Pearl" or "JFP Functional Pearl" you'll find a ton.

Comment: I cant completely agree with you. I think that CS is some sort of an extension of the mathematics into the world of computation. Heuristics are only things you see in practice, not in theory. Edge cases - exist also in mathematics. Approximations? Yes, this is a thing only CS has. But it depends on how you define it. From theoretical perspective, its the same as every theory, and from practical perspectives its mostly heuristics. But what I find beautiful and unique to CS are the impossibility results.